# Initialize an IEnumerable<T> to a new List<T>

Tags: c#, list, linq, generics, ienumerable

I have a class like this:

```
public class ItemList
{
    [JsonProperty("items")]
    public IEnumerable<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to initialize empty list, like this:

```
var newItemList = new ItemList
{
    Items = new List<Item>()
};
```

But the `Items` remains an `IEnumerable`  and I can't use `Add` or other methods of a list.

Comment: is it necessary to use IEnumerable<Item> in class? if so you have to cast that property in a list where you want to use List's methods.

Comment: If you now that Items is always a List, you should change it to IList<Item>. Otherwise, there might be a reason this is only IEnumerable.

Comment: The type of the variable/property (ignoring `dynamic`) determines what methods are available to call via that variable. The runtime type of the object being referenced does not.

Comment: @PMF `IList` is not appropriate, since `Add` is not always "available" on a `IList` e.g array.

Comment: So you want your class to have a public property of type `IEnumerable<Item>`, in a way that anyone could treat the property like is was a `List<Item>`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use either of the below two options.

1. You can use List Initializer like below

   ```
    var itemList = new ItemList() {
        Items = new List<Item>() {
            new Item() { Name = "One" },
            new Item() { Name = "Two" }
        }
    };
   ```
2. You can initialize the list fully and then assign it to the `Items`
3. Much better approach would be to use a Builder pattern which would help in constructing the `ItemList` as described at https://code-maze.com/fluent-builder-recursive-generics/

Comment: I thought about the same, however, *"I want to initialize empty list"*

Comment: You can initialize empty list. But, you may not be able to add to it. You can write a method in the `ItemList` to `AddItem` by that way, you don't have to expose implementation details to consumers.

Comment: You may expose `IEnumerable` to outside world at instance level store a `List` and expose only `Add` method.

Answer (score 0):

Why not declare it as a list

```
public class ItemList
{
    [JsonProperty("items")]
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

List is `IEnumerable` by extention, so it would make sense to declare it as a list and have all the methods in place.

Since you already declared is `public IEnumerable<Item> Items { get; set; }` it will not change.

You can do this:

```
Items = new List<Item>();
```

and even

```
ItemList itemlist = new itemlist();
itemlist.Items = new List<Item>();
((List<Item>)itemlist.Items).Add(new Item());
```

But `((List<Item>)itemlist.Items).Add(new Item());` is not safe. It will work when you initialize as a list, but it will lead to a runtime exception if you try to cast from some other `IEnumerable` type.

Answer (score 0):

Having IEnumerable allows you to accomplish one of the SOLID principles that say that you must rely on abstraction rather than on concrete classes. Meaning that you can store whatever implementation of IEnumerable within that property (List, HashSet, etc ...).

You have to convert IEnumerable to List If you want to use the Add method implemented by the List class

```
var myList = newItemList.ToList<T>();
myList.Add(new T());
```

where T is your concrete class.

Answer (score -1):

Sure you can, just cast it:

```
(Items as List<Item>).Add(someItem);
```

It's gonna get pretty boring casting it all the time, perhaps:

```
public class ItemList
{
    private List<Item> _items - new List<Item>;
    [JsonProperty("items")]
    public IEnumerable<Item> Items { get => _items; private set => _items = value as List<string>; }
}
```

Then inside the class you can use `_items`.

**I recommend you make that setter private** and set the items to be a List *internally* to the class; the cast is needed on the set, but if someone else passes in an IEnumerable that isn't a List it will cause the items collection to be set to null.

If you're going to make the decision that external classes will see an IEnumerable but you're going to have it be a List, then you shouldn't give anyone using your class the opportunity to change it to something that's not a List..

If you're only ever going to set the list once (never change it for a new instance) e.g. in the constructor, then you can make the property readonly instead

Comment: `(Items as List<Item>)?.Add(someItem);` if `Items` was something else than a List (not my DV)

Comment: `(Items as List<Item>).Add(someItem);` Could very well lead to null reference exceptions. At the very least you should add a warning in your answer.

Comment: Why would it be something else than a list; OP is making the decision that it will be

Comment: @AthanasiosKataras see the part where I recommend making the setter private. This question is about correcting the misconception that storing a list into an ienumerable gets rid of the Add method